# Ошибка при доступе из Activity в Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Использую [пример](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/12/access-view-inside-fragment-from.html) для работы с `Fragment`. Если в классе `AndroidFragmentActivity` из кода:

```
buttonSendToFragment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String text = textActivity.getText().toString();
    TextView textFragment = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fragmenttext);
    textFragment.setText("тестовый текст в листенере");
   }});
```

вынести строки:

```
TextView textFragment = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fragmenttext);
textFragment.setText("тестовый текст вне листенера");
```

вне листенера, то приложение завершается с ошибкой.
1) Почему? Если уже был установлен Fragment раннее:

```
// get an instance of FragmentTransaction from your Activity 
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

//add a fragment 
myFragment = new MyFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.myfragment, myFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

2) Как можно исправить данную ситуацию? 
Просто мне необходимо сразу получать текстовое поле внутри фрагмента и использовать в активити, а тут такое.

Comment: Покажите лог если не трудно.

Comment: @РасулA-ев, там пишется `NullPointerException` в строке `textFragment.setText("тестовый текст вне листенера");`, т.е. при обращении к TextView.

Comment: Вынесите это из метода `onCreate ` в метод `onResume`

Comment: @РасулA-ев, да, так работает. А почему он сразу не видит элементы фрагмента, если он уже сразу установлен??

Answer (score 1):

Вынесите это из метода `onCreate` в метод onResume. Ошибка возникает потому, что метод фрагмента `onCreateView` вызывается после того как выполнится метод `onCreate`.

Прочитайте про жизненный цикл фрагментов: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/fragment-lifecycle.php

Comment: Да, спасибо. Заметил. А есть ли еще какой-то способ обхода этой ситуации, только с манипуляцией внутри своего фрагмента?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под `внутри своего фрагмента` ?

Comment: [http://blog.iamsuleiman.com/using-bottom-navigation-view-android-design-support-library/](в разделе Creating Fragments) вроде бы показано обращение к элементу View фрагмента. Я это имел ввиду.

Comment: В данном примере передаются данные во фрагмент через `Bundle`

Comment: Заметил, спасибо!!

Comment: Если вам помогло, отметьте ответ как правильный.

Comment: С удовольствием, но не хватает рейтинга. Можете отметить вопрос как полезный?